# usb microphone suggestions for eliminating background noise

Tags: microphone

I got a Behringer C-1U for recording vocals in ableton, but unfortunately it's picking up a lot of background white noise, and I have to turn gain up 100% on my computer to even hear my vocals. I'm just looking for good suggestions for mics around the $100 range that eliminate background noise but have natural sounding audio quality. I know the Rode Procaster is great at eliminating background noise, but it doesn't really sound natural and it's too expensive. I plan on using this mic for both music production and voice overs for my cartoon I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a denoiser plugin.. should usually come stock.
eq the audio - take out the low end or a bit from the high end.
-then boost the lower mid

mess around with compressor settings

get a pop filter

pop filter plugin lol

get a foam filter

etc

Comment: Done all that, the white noise is across the whole audio spectrum so i cant just cut bands out and trying to take it out with audacity makes the vocals sound weird. Compressor makes it worse because its purpose is to make quite louder and loud quieter to even out overall volume.